# C++ double-declaration or no declaration issue

Tags: c++

I'm writting a simple game and I've had it finished, except it had a bad file structure and every class was just an .h file.

I've decided to split the declarations and definitions into separate files, because I ran into circular inclusion issue (which was predictable).

Now that I've split them into separate files, my .h files contains:

- declaration of class, it's methods, enum and other variables.
- inclusion of neccessary files that .cpp or .h requires (so basically .cpp includes it's .h file and it get's all the inclusions it needs).

While my .cpp file contains:

- definition of methods.

Okay, now that you have a general idea on how my files are structured, here's the issue I'm having.

Spaceship.cpp requires cursorPos variable that exists in Core.h

Core.h includes Spaceship.h because it requires it for a method.

If I include Core.h inside Spaceship.h, I get double-declaration.

If I don't include Core.h inside Spaceship.h, I get no-declaration.

I'm clueless, should I create a 'Helper' class that contains variables I want to cross-share between classes?

**EDIT**
Code as requested

Spaceship.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SPACESHIP_H
#define SPACESHIP_H

#include "Vector2D.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Missile.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Core.h"

extern const int SPACESHIP_SHOOT_DELAY = 50;
extern const int SPACESHIP_MAX_VELOCITY = 10;
extern const float SPACESHIP_VELOCITY_GAIN = 0.05;
extern const float SPACESHIP_VELOCITY_LOSS = -0.15;
class Spaceship : public Entity
{
    public:
        Vector2D position = Vector2D(0, 0);
        Vector2D direction = Vector2D(0, 0);
        SDL_Texture* texture;

        //Required by rendering
        SDL_Rect renderbox = { 0, 0, 32, 32 };
        SDL_Rect boundingbox = { 0, 0, 32, 32 };
        SDL_Point center = { 16, 16 };

        int lastShot = SDL_GetTicks();
        int angle = 0;
        float velocity = 0;
        void Update() override;
        void Render(SDL_Renderer* renderer) override;
        void Fire();

        Spaceship();
        ~Spaceship();
};
#endif
```

Core.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CORE_H
#define CORE_H

#include "Vector2D.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Spaceship.h"

extern Vector2D cursorPos = Vector2D();
class Core
{
    private:
        static bool run;

    public:
        static SDL_Window* window;
        static SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        static SDL_Cursor* cursor;
        static int screenWidth;
        static int screenHeight;

        static void Initialize();
        static void ProcessEvents(SDL_Event* e);
        static void Update();
        static void Render();
        static int Execute();
        static void Cleanup();

        Core();
        ~Core();
};

#endif
```

And the errors I'm getting
[image]

Comment: Are you using include guards?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: Not a quick solution but you shouldn't rely on global variables.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon please elaborate.

Comment: Are you really using Objective C++? If so, why are your files named `.cpp` and not `.mm`? If not, you should remove the tag.

Comment: @sepp2k done, I've kinda went ahead of myself

Comment: @Netheous I see that you are already using include guards (`#ifndef CORE_H` etc..). It seems your problem is different from what your original question suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of global variables is an anti-pattern, and for good reasons. However describing all the many reasons why one should avoid global state, is a topic for another day. In your case, you are having trouble with your specific implementation of the global variables. While I would strongly recommend that you revisit your design, and lower the amount of global state, I will try to present a solution and explanation to the problems you are facing.

One problem is understanding the include mechanics of C++, when you include a file in C++ you are basically inserting the contents of that file, in that place in your code. So if you have anything declared in a header file, it will be declared where it is included. If you include a file multiple times, you will insert it multiple times, and thereby declare your variables multiple times. As an example consider my header variables.h:

```
int someGlobalVariable = 100;
```

Now consider a second header file: functionality.h, that looks like this:

```
#include "variables.h"

void foo(int number);
```

And finally a source file called functionality.cpp:

```
#include "variables.h"
#include "functionality.h"

void foo(int number) {
    // Do something
}
```

This will give a compiler error, because our variable someGlobalVariable is defined twice. But why is it that? If we try to do the inclusion we will see why:

```
// variables.h
int someGlobalVariable = 100;

// functionality.h
int someGlobalVariable = 100;  // <-- included from functionality.h

void foo(int number);

void foo(int number) {
    // Do something
}
```

As you can see the variable is inserted twice, and that of course is not good, the compile will complain, and for good reasons. The forward declaration of `foo` is entirely legal though.

We could ofcourse add include guards to our header files:

The file variables.h:

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H_
#define VARIABLES_H_

int someGlobalVariable = 100;

#endif
```

The file functionality.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONALITY_H_
#define FUNCTIONALITY_H_
#include "variables.h"
#include "functionality.h"

void foo(int number) {
    // Do something
}

#endif
```

This would cause the `someGlobalVariable` variable to only be included once in our .cpp source file. However this does not make it truly global. Remember since C++ inserts the contents of the file, at the location that we include the file, we will still declare the variable once for each source independent source file that includes it.

Instead of a global we would have a new instance, for every source module, which is not what you want. You need to ensure that the variable is declared once only, and then referred to. This means that we need to declare the variable in a file that is not included (or at most included once). Let us put it in a .cpp file instead.

So a .cpp file named globals.cpp:

```
int someGlobalVariable.cpp = 100;
```

The variable.h file now needs to be modified to read:

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H_
#define VARIABLES_H_

extern int someGlobalVariable;

#endif
```

The [`extern`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) keyword instructs the linker that the variable is declared in another source unit. So the code after the include guards have been added will look like this, when we insert the includes:

```
// variables.h
extern int someGlobalVariable;

// functionality.h
// Since VARIABLES_H_ is now defined we will not insert the contents.

void foo(int number);

void foo(int number) {
    // Do something
}
```

The linker will then know to look for the declaration of someGlobalVariable in another object file. Most importantly all source units that refer to the `extern int someGlobalVariable` will share the same instance.

In your case you should remove the `=` from the declaration, the variable should be declared in a source unit of its own. So your line:

```
extern Vector2D cursorPos = Vector2D();
```

Becomes:

```
extern Vector2D cursorPos;
```

And then in a source (.cpp) file you declare the variable like this:

```
Vector2D cursorPos = Vector2D();
```

Comment: Thank you greatly for help.

Answer (score 1):

Definitions of variables also should be located in .cpp files. Headers should declare it with `extern` keyword:

Core.h:

```
extern Point cursorPos;
```

Core.cpp:

```
#include "Core.h"
...
Point cursorPos;
```

Comment: That generates even more errors, quadruple declaration in certain cases.
Am I missing something?

Comment: It would be a good answer if it insisted on the fact that global variables are _evil_.

Comment: Everyone says it, but I need to access cursorPos and I'm a freak that hates to have two variables in two different places that do the exact same thing.

+ I need to access MAX_SHIP_VELOCITY from Spaceship.h and adding extern pops quadruple declaration error.

Comment: @Netheous probably you did something wrong. Generally you can write `extern` declaration any number of times and it will not cause an error: https://ideone.com/63ixwV.

Comment: @Zefick just noticed, I had circular inclusion - Core.h -> Spaceship.h, Spaceship.h -> Core.h.

But now that I remove include Core.h from Spaceship.h - cursorPos is undeclared.

The only solution I can think of is adding a middleman, a Helper class that has these variables and both Core.h and Spaceship.h including it.

Comment: So what do you guys suggest, having a file that has all these constants? like SPACESHIP_MAX_VELOCITY?

Comment: @Netheous whatever you think you gain by having fewer instances of variables, it is not worth it. A Point variable does not take up a lot of memory, micro optimizations like this, is not something that you will benefit from. Keep variable delaration out of header files, and if you must have a single global instance, use an `extern` defined variable in a header, and declare it in a single source file. Like suggested here. Remember the basics and include the header guards as suggested by another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put `#pragma once` as the top line of every header file. This resolves the multiple-times-included issue (i.e. it will ensure that the compiler will not re-include the code of an include file which it has already included before)

Comment: Stricly speaking `#pragma once` is not standard C++... Personally I would prefer a regular header:  
`#ifndef SOMETHING_H_`  
`#define SOMETHING_H_`  
`...`  
`#endif`

Comment: Even with `#pragma once` you will get a linkage error if you imclude the header from different cpp-s. Variables always should be declared with `extern`.

Comment: @Tommy Anderson Strictly speaking, names containing double underscores are reserved for the implementation ;). But I agree, use good header guards, which are portable.

Comment: @oisyn Strictly speaking "double underscore" is two consecutive underscores, not like in my example. See §5.10.3.1 ;-)

Comment: That's what I meant. It must be my mobile phone's font rendering then, because those underscores look awfully long :). Mea culpa.

Comment: @TommyAndersen I've added the inclusion guards, but it pops multum of errors regarding variables being already defined for other variables that have born extern before them and inclusion guards added.

Comment: @Netheous it is difficult to answer, without seeing your code, perhaps you could add some code to your question, so it will be easier to answer.